# Not able to invoke js chaincode in hyperledger fabric 2.2

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

**ESCC invoke result: response:<status:500 message:"make sure the chaincode basic2 has been successfully defined on channel mychannel and try again: chaincode definition for 'basic2' exists, but chaincode is not installed"**

I package the js chaincode then installed then approved as well as committed, but even after all process i am not able to create container as well as invoke the methods. i have followed the documentation: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/deploy_chaincode.html

Hyperledger fabric 2.2
Ubuntu 18.04
Docker version 19.03.8

please can anyone tell me where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As the error indicates, it seems that your chaincode hasn't been installed correctly, so I would try those steps again.